# Android block children touch events

Tags: android, events, touch

I have a `ViewGroup` and I want to block the touch events to all of his children views. How do I do that?

Comment: give him an own ontouchlistener and return true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a method you can override in the **ViewGroup** called **onInterceptTouchEvent**, which gives you these godly powers.

```
@Override
 public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
   // code to block events from children here
 }
```

It's purpose:

> **boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)** - called whenever a
>   touch event is detected with this ViewGroup or a child of it as
>   target. If this function returns true, the MotionEvent will be
>   intercepted, meaning it will be not be passed on to the child, but
>   rather to the onTouchEvent of this View.

See the Android API [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29)